# Xcode 4 and git merge --no-ff

Tags: xcode, git, merge

I'm liking the git integration in Xcode 4 but when doing a merge it seems Xcode will only do the default merge with fast forward. I like to keep my feature branch lines separate. Does anyone know if it's possible to have Xcode's merge be no-fast-forward?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try and set the config

```
 branch.<name>.mergeoptions
```

> Sets default options for merging into branch .
> **The syntax and supported options are the same as those of [git-merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)**, but option values containing whitespace characters are currently not supported.

So you can add the `--no-ff` there, and see if XCode4 respects the config for your `feature` branch.

As [Yitschak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830676/yitschak) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572567/xcode-4-and-git-merge-no-ff/5576858#comment72778187_5576858):

```
git config branch.<name>.mergeoptions --no-ff
```

---

Update 2019, with XCode 10: [DaveDude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937780/davedude) repors:

> With Xcode 10, this approach doesn't seem to work anymore.
>
> Now, I set [`merge.ff=false`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-mergeff) and that gives me the desired behaviour again.

Comment: I just did a quick test project and can verify this does indeed work. I set --no-ff on master and when I merged in a topic branch using Xcode it did not fast forward. Thanks.

Comment: type in terminal: **git config branch.<name>.mergeoptions --no-ff** (for new comers like me). I don't think it's working for master. but it does work for my "develop" branch

Comment: @Yitschak Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: with Xcode 10 this approach doesn't seem to work anymore.  Now, I set merge.ff=false and that gives me the desired behaviour again

Comment: @DaveDude Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: So you can not do this configuration in Xcode itself; you have to do it in the terminal. Is this correct?

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon Yes, any `git config` command is to be done in command line (terminal). It will then be interpreted by XCode.

Comment: @Vonc Thanks for clarifying. This approach looks like its for each branch. Is there a universal git config for any branch in any project?